# how to search shared library when running an executable?

Tags: linux, hyperlink, executable, shared

I have an excutable and a shared library in same directory, the executable running well, however, after moving the shared library to other pos, I can not run the executable showing can not find libxxx.so

I want to know why it happens?

Answer (score 1):

You can move the library to some standard library path. It is defined in `/etc/ld.so.conf`. The loader will only find libraries defined in there. In the other hand, you can also use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable to put your shared library path. It makes sure the path is searched first